# XSD assert to ensure a specific children exists

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I want to check if a child with a specific attribute exists.

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mc:PropertyGroupStructure xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
 xmlns:mc="de.mycompany.propertygroupstructure"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="de.mycompany.propertygroupstructure file:PGroupStructure.xsd">
 <mc:Property id="awesome" rename="Awesome Renaming" />
 <mc:Category name="Common">
  <mc:Property id="Note"/>
  <mc:Property id="Other" />
 </mc:Category>
 <mc:Property id="aaa"></pc:Property>
</mc:PropertyGroupStructure>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1" targetNamespace="de.mycompany.propertygroupstructure"
    xmlns="de.mycompany.propertygroupstructure">
    <xs:element name="PropertyGroupStructure" type="PropertyGroupStructureType">
        <xs:unique name="UniqueId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./* | ./*/*"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertyGroupStructureType">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Property" type="PropertyType"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Category" type="CategoryType"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:assert test="Property[@id eq 'awesome']" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="PropertyType">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="rename" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:assert test="(@id ne 'awesome') or 
                         (@id eq 'awesome' and exists(@rename) and (@rename eq 'Awesome Renaming')) />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CategoryType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Property" type="PropertyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But Xerces always tells me "Assertion not succeeded".

Maybe the XPath syntax is wrong?

Edit: I replaced the original simplified example by a complete one.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that your assertion is testing against `ele/@name` but your XML has `ele/@attr`.  Correcting that problem and simplifying yields the following assertion,

```
<xs:assert test="ele[@attr eq 'awesome']" />
```

which will validate successfully against your XML, as requested.

Comment: Thanks! It's not working. I edited my OP and replaced the simplified example by a complete one. It's still not working. Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hm, maybe any advice? :-) Thanks!

Comment: Now your XML has `rename="Awesome Rename"` yet your XSD asserts `rename="Awesome Renaming"`.   Separately, your assertion also can be simplified using basic Boolean algebra.

Comment: Ok, that was simply a typo. I meant:  <mc:Property id="awesome" rename="Awesome Renaming" />